# Auto-resize iframe based on content height

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a site on my server that is pulling in an iframe from an external site in which I do not have access.

I want the iframe to resize the height based on the content that is being pulled in so the page as a whole looks like a single page.

*I do not need to know how to get rid of the scroll bars.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. There is no way to interact with an iframe with JavaScript. That would have serious security consequences so browsers don't allow it.

Comment: This is correct. Cross-domain issues prevent the browser from being able to detect the content of a non-local iframe.

Comment: Yep, and the whole reason why the browser prevents access to iframes is to prevent against XSS and XSR attacks

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'the height of the content'? Is it an image, block of text, a table? You might be able to get round it using some kind of AJAX, but it will depend on the type of content in the iframe.

Comment: The content within the iFrame is always changing, which means the height is always changing too. I'm basically importing another site.
http://www.talkingdogtees.com

Answer (score -1):

in css try

```
#frame_ID{
  height:auto;
}
```

I tried a whole bunch of things in css to see if there was any way to tell when the iframe didn't have a scrollbar and I found no solution so.  Like the comment says this will not work.