# Is there any way to set IFrame's height dynamic?

Tags: html, iframe

```
<div class="LHSChunk" style="width:690px;float:left;">
    <div class="DetailComments" runat="server" id="CommentVisible">
        <iframe id="iframeComments" runat="server" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width: 700px; height: 400px; visibility: visible;"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I wanted to set my **iframe's height as dynamic** one based on the page displayed in iframe. For your info I'm using same domain page in iframe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-resize iframe based on content height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314276/auto-resize-iframe-based-on-content-height)

Comment: That duplicate is only a duplicate if the page in the iframe is *from an external domain*. *If* the iframe content (via 'src') is on the *same domain* then you can communicate the 'inside' size back to the parent.

Comment: For your info, I'm using same domain page on iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function resizeIframe(obj) {
            obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
        }
    </script>
```

in aspx,

```
<iframe id="iframeComments" runat="server" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width: 690px; visibility: visible;"></iframe>
```

in aspx.cs,

```
iframeComments.Attributes.Add("onload", "resizeIframe(this)");
```

Thanks.